# pass data from joined table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have built an eloquent query for inner join of two tables. I am getting data from the database, debugged using `dump($ordered_books);`

```
function fetchData()
    {
        $ordered_books = DB::table('ordered_books')
        -> join('books', 'books.id','=','ordered_books.BookID')
        -> select('books.BookName', 'ordered_books.BilledNum','ordered_books.BilledDate','ordered_books.Qunatity',
        'ordered_books.Price', 'ordered_books.BillPaid', 'ordered_books.Remarks' )
        -> get()->toArray();

        dump($ordered_books);

        return compact('ordered_books');
    }
```

But when I pass the data to view page, I am getting error:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

How to solve this error?

View page block

```
@foreach($ordered_books as $data)
 <tr>
     <td> {{$data['BookName']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['BilledDate']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['BilledNum']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['Qunatity']}} </td>
     <td> {{$data['Price']}} </td>
     @if($data['BillPaid'] === 1)
                <td>PAID</td> 
            @else
                <td style="color:red">DUE</td>
            @endif
     <td> {{$data['Remarks']}} </td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$data` variable is not an array. It is a class. Try this:

```
$data->BookName
```

The variable from the get() function is of the type [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) of stdClass classes.  You run toArray() on the Collection. That means, you have an array of StdClasses. You still have to use `$data->variable`

Comment: but he says `toArray()` at end of the query

Comment: Hasan, yes, but that only works for the collection. It will be an array of StdClass anyway.

Comment: The toArray() function actually doesn't have to be there. You can run foreach on a Collection directly.

Comment: @Peter I changed the view block and it worked. Thank You. But one question should I use  `-> get()->toArray();` or remove Array, which is more better. Please explain.

Comment: @nischalinn You don't need toArray(), because you can run foreach on a collection directly. The result will be the same, so you just save some CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

I checked out what comes when we used `toArray()` method.. And you can see that in below, collection turn into array but items not.. they're still object..

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => {#254 ▶}
  1 => {#255 ▶}
  2 => {#256 ▶}
  3 => {#257 ▶}
  4 => {#258 ▶}
  5 => {#259 ▶}
]
```

As Peter Matisko mentioned, you should say

```
$data->BookName
```

Answer (score 0):

Use object notation to fetch the values as shown below

```
 @foreach($ordered_books as $data)
  <tr>
   <td> {{$data->BookName}} </td>
   <td> {{$data->BilledDate}} </td>
   <td> {{$data->BilledNum}} </td>
   ...
 </tr>
@endforeach
```